# Overriding Standard Account Detail Page when Person Accounts are enabled

Tags: visualforce

We have an org that has **Person Accounts** enabled. For user experience purposes, we have implemented a custom tabbed visualforce detail page for Person Accounts, and overrode the account view action with the new visualforce page.

Through testing, we found that from certain existing objects, the ContactID is referenced in a lookup, rather than the AccountID. When clicked, it would take the user to the Person Account ***Contact*** standard detail page, rather than the Account detail page we are overriding.

Since we are using Business Contacts, we didn't want to do away with the standard Business Contact detail view, so we implemented the following visualforce page and overrode the view action for Contacts:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" showHeader="true" sidebar="true" tabStyle="contact"  >
<script>
    var businesscontact = "{!Contact.RecordType.Name}";
    if(businesscontact != "Business"){
        window.location.href = '/' + '{!Contact.AccountID}';
    } 
</script>

<social:profileViewer entityId="{!Contact.id}" rendered="{!(Contact.RecordType.Name == 'Business')}"/> 

<apex:detail relatedList="true" title="true" inlineEdit="true" rendered="{!(Contact.RecordType.Name == 'Business')}"/>
```

If you are visiting a contact, who is a business contact, you'd see the "standard detail" view replicated in the visualforce page. If it was not a business contact, then it is a Person Account and the user is redirected to the Person Account record of the contact.

Are there any alternative solutions or best practices we should follow in this situation?

Comment: Seems like you pretty much have it figured out. Are there any difficulties you're facing you'd like help with?

Comment: I would agree with @AdrianLarson, it's a matter of implementing the RecordTypes that distinguish the two types of contacts.

Comment: I think I'm just concerned about future proofing this. I agree that RecordTypes are the way to conditionally render or redirect, but the redirect felt hacky - and that made me a little uncomfortable :)